# Shank installation problem

Tags: installation, games, install-from-source

after several attempts I was not able to install Shank.I've download the bin and .deb (for 64bit architecture) files. The bin shows this message on launch: "No such file or directory". The Deb not installed correctly. If someone managed to find a solution or workaround to install this game I hope will help me too.
Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution:
by installing the deb for 32 bit I realized I was missing some libraries (in addition to ia32-libs and libc6). I first solved this problem by giving this command: `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Then I got another error: `Message: SDL_GL_LoadLibrary Error: Failed loading libGL.so.1`

Obviously, these libraries were properly installed. Without going into details I had to link the libraries by hand. I realized then that could also an easier solution through Synaptic install the following packages: `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`.

After that the next problem was the black screen while playing, which I solved by replacing the executable in `/Shank/bin` with this: http://treefort.icculus.org/smb/smb-linux-mesa-hotfix-test.tar.bz2.

I hope it will be useful to someone. If you need more help or more details please feel free to contact me.

Comment: The link that you gave is for super meat boy not for shank. Can you please give the solution for black screen in shank.

Comment: I missed the link, sorry for the mistake.
This one should be the right one: http://treefort.icculus.org/shank/shank-linux-mesa-hotfix-test.tar.bz2